# get jquery.data() related to an element from a saved html using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some html that I want to save in database for a later retrieve.

Let's imagine the html is a simple div

```
<div id="mydiv">This is my div</div>
```

I use [jQuery.data()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) to store some information related to that div like this :

```
$("#mydiv").data("divNumber", "5").data("divRole", "adminMessage") .....
```

Then finally I save the html in database, but I would like to be able to get those information later when I need them :

```
var myHtml = { here I get the html from my database }

$("body").append(myHtml);

console.log( $("#mydiv").data("divNumber") ); // I want it to show 5

console.log( $("#mydiv").data("divRole") ); // I want it to show adminMessag
```

from my understanding of jquery.data() I think it will just store those data information temporary in an internal cache and if I save the html in the database, and I leave the page, they will be lost !!

So is there a way to keep those jquery.data() information and retrieve them whenever I want ? or maybe there is another "better" way to achieve the same thing (I am not looking for localStorage method)

Comment: Why would you want to save the html to the database instead of just the data?

Comment: @Musa I need the html to be manipulated later, so I retrieve the html from the database and I append it to my page, then I would like to have those data values still there, do you understand what I mean ?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the `.data()` to data attributes on the html and save that.

```js
$("#mydiv").data("divNumber", "5").data("divRole", "adminMessage");
$.each($("#mydiv").data(), function(k,v){
  $("#mydiv").attr("data-"+k.replace(/[A-Z]/g, "-$&"), v);
});
var toDatabase = $("#mydiv")[0].outerHTML;
//save to database
// ...
// retrieve from database
var fromDatabase = $(toDatabase);
$('body').append(fromDatabase.data('divNumber'));
$('body').append('<br>');
$('body').append(fromDatabase.data('divRole'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv">This is my div</div>
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, I tried to avoid data attributes because I have a lot of key/values to store and I don't want my html to be a mess because I have an option to edit it in the fly

Comment: Using data attributes is the best way to save the data with the html. If you don't want to do that save the data in another field in the database and just add the data back to the div when you append it back to the document

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a database in the browser which works across all platforms consistently, despite each browser having different underlying storage mechanisms try PouchDB. It is great! You can keep it just in your browser session which will persist until the user clears their data OR you can have it persist to a CouchDB database server.

http://pouchdb.com/

There are many good CouchDB providers if you dont want to setup your own although that is simple to do. IBM Cloudant is free until your usage is above $50 per month:

https://cloudant.com/

It is very simple to use, see [here](http://pouchdb.com/getting-started.html#creating_a_database). A couple lines of code to create a db object and a few to put / fetch.  Then one line each to setup a remote copy and one line to live sync to it.

Comment: thank you for that, but it's not what I am looking for, I have my server database, I just want my html to keep those .data("property") when I retrieve it from the database

Comment: Ah, I see from your edit now. Guessing when you save to the database the .data(..) fields you specified are dropped?

Comment: I am not sure if they will be dropped or not, and this is what I want to know, I have no access to the server right now, I am just coding the javascript part in my computer, so I want to be sure they will be persist and hopefully I can understand jquery.data() a little more

Comment: Can you post the code showing how you are saving and retrieving? I expect that it will not persist, but not sure!